# SPFx - React component fail to load on site page

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx-webparts, spfx-extensions, react, gulp

I was trying to import and using react component from: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-calendar-timeline

It is just rendering normal on workbench:

[image]

When I try to bundle and deploy to site page it fail on first load with error:

```
[SPLoaderError.loadComponentError]: Failed to load component "51797110-0806-4320-8cd2-e69fe594805b" (ResourceTimelineWpWebPart). Original error: Failed to load entry point from component "51797110-0806-4320-8cd2-e69fe594805b" (ResourceTimelineWpWebPart). Original error: Error loading https://component-id.invalid/51797110-0806-4320-8cd2-e69fe594805b_0.0.1 Super expression must either be null or a function

INNERERROR: Failed to load entry point from component "51797110-0806-4320-8cd2-e69fe594805b" (ResourceTimelineWpWebPart). Original error: Error loading https://component-id.invalid/51797110-0806-4320-8cd2-e69fe594805b_0.0.1 Super expression must either be null or a function CALLSTACK: Error at t [as constructor] (https://modernb.akamai.odsp.cdn.office.net/files/sp-client/sp-pages-assembly_en-us_2aa07b950bd1d595b56070cdbc072776.js:67:19894) at new t (https://modernb.akamai.odsp.cdn.office.net/files/sp-client/sp-pages-assembly_en-us_2aa07b950bd1d595b56070cdbc072776.js:68:9374) at Function.e.buildErrorWithVerboseLog (https://modernb.akamai.odsp.cdn.office.net/files/sp-client/sp-pages-assembly_en-us_2aa07b950bd1d595b56070cdbc072776.js:68:46574) at Function.e.buildLoadComponentError (https://modernb.akamai.odsp.cdn.office.net/files/sp-client/sp-pages-assembly_en-us_2aa07b950bd1d595b56070cdbc072776.js:68:42619) at https://modernb.akamai.odsp.cdn.office.net/files/sp-client/chunk.systemjs-component-loader_en-us_111a8e4c34276ac79a3b.js:1:11895
```

[image: Fail on site page]

Does it any related with bundle and package steps?

Any tips on where I'm going wrong would be appreciate.

My sources: https://github.com/DuongVoSP/ResourceTimelineWP.git

Comment: Did you use `--ship` with gulp bundle & gulp package-solution commands?

Comment: Sure, I always do it when deploy

Comment: can you post what `npm ls -g --depth=0` returns when you run it, please?

Comment: Here the results:
C:\Users\Duong Vo\AppData\Roaming\npm
+-- @microsoft/generator-sharepoint@1.11.0
+-- bit-bin@14.8.8
+-- create-react-app@4.0.0
+-- eslint@7.10.0
+-- firebase-tools@8.16.2
+-- gulp@4.0.2
+--  error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'E:\Client\NOWA\NOWA.SPFx.AggregatedCalendar\refs
`-- yo@3.1.1

Comment: npm ERR! peer dep missing: graphql@^14.3.1, required by @apollo/react-hooks@3.1.5
npm ERR! peer dep missing: graphql@^14.4.1, required by express-graphql@0.9.0
npm ERR! peer dep missing: graphql@^14.3.1, required by @apollo/react-common@3.1.4
npm ERR! peer dep missing: acorn@^7 || ^8, required by acorn-stage3@3.1.0
npm ERR! error in C:\Users\Duong Vo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\react-form-webpart: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'E:\Client\NOWA\NOWA.SPFx.AggregatedCalendar\refs'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue log on repository said

[Latest versions of interactjs break production builds](https://github.com/namespace-ee/react-calendar-timeline/issues/754)

So I just need to change package version
Re-install node_modules package and deploy again.